# How to match only expressions containing not equal groups?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to capture only expressions with a difference in given groups by using regular expressions.
For example I need to capture these (in bold):

`;TEXT;2;34;1;0;;;;;;3200;`
`PRINT_Polohopis.dgn;Different TEXT;2;64;1;0;;;;;;3200;`

but not these (if it is the same):

`;TEXT;2;34;1;0;;;;;;3200;`
`PRINT_Polohopis.dgn;TEXT;2;64;1;0;;;;;;3200;`

So far I managed to create this regex:

```
^;([\w\s]*;).*\n(?:[\w\s_\.]*);(?:(?!(\1))(\K[\w\s]*;))
```

which works only if I include a semicolon inside the capturing groups.
Is it possible to capture those groups in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
/^;([^;]+);.*?\n[^;]+;(?!\1;)([^;]+)/
```

[Try it online](https://www.regex101.com/r/zW5gK2/2)

The trick here is that a negative lookthahead is used to make sure `\1` (back reference) is not at the desired position:

```
/^;                                 / # Start of string and literal ;
   ([^;]+);                           # Capture all but ; followed by literal ;
           .*?\n                      # Match rest of line
                [^;]+;                # Match all but ; followed by literal ;
                      (?!\1;)         # Negative lookahead to make sure captured
                                      # group is no at this position, followed
                                      # by literal ;
                             ([^;]+)  # Capture all but ;
```

Comment: There is still a bug - In case the difference is at the end of the second captured group (for example TEXT vs. TEXT1).

Comment: @PavelVicha That's true, it's easy to fix though, just use `(?!\1;)` instead of `(?!\1)`

Comment: `.` matches everything but newlines, `*` repeats it zero or more times. `?` can actually be omitted there as it makes the match non greedy. But it wont matter since `.` doesn't match newline.